# "Interesting" questions tab became irrelevant

Tags: support, interesting-page

After the recent SOF database migration (was it?), I noticed that the questions that pop up in the "interesting" tab have become very irrelevant. (if irrelevant is the right choice of words).

Has it been reset or something? Now, it shows me all sorts of questions related to many, many fields that I have never opened, asked, answered a question about.

---

The discussion in the comments went out of hand a bit. I really thought something went wrong with the interesting page, but with the help of the formula page, I can now somewhat predict and control the questions. Thanks.

Comment: Anything in the formula on http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/ that stands out as potentially-gone-wrong?

Comment: To me, the interesting list looks well within the formula for the homepage.

Comment: Can't see any change. Can you be more specific? Do you have favorite tags?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd , I do, they usually fill the page, with the exception of 2 - 5 questions. (am checking the formula).

Comment: Strangely enough I think the “Interesting” questions tab was always irrelevant...

Comment: I checked the formula, and cannot tell how an html5, canvas tagged question with 0 votes can end up on my interesting page. It's score is basically, 0. (So, I am assuming other questions are getting negative scores and not showing up). I have to express here, I'd rather see an answered question in my field, than a totally irrelevant question with a question scrore of 1000.

Comment: Then add more tags to your ignored list if they are so irrelevant to you, or use a tag search instead (tip: search for `[tag] [or] [othertag] [or] [thirdtag]`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, that's what am doing now. And I have come to appreciate how diverse the programming topics are on SOF.. I am adding way too many ignore tags.

Comment: Maybe to added by mistake some ignored tag?